# "Unknown signal 11" problem while submitting the code to coursera. Problem gets resolved if I use a 2-D vector instead of a 2-D array

Tags: c++, algorithm, coursera-api

**Task.** Given  gold bars, find the maximum weight of gold that fits into a bag of capacity .

**Input Format.** The first line of the input contains the capacity  of a knapsack and the number  of bars of gold. The next line contains  integers 0,1, . . . ,−1 defining the weights of the bars of gold.

**Constraints.** 1 ≤  ≤ 104; 1 ≤  ≤ 300; 0 ≤ 0, . . . ,−1 ≤ 105.

**Output Format.** Output the maximum weight of gold that fits into a knapsack of capacity .

I have implemented a solution for this problem. It worked really well. But while submitting it to coursera, i got "unknown signal 11" so I tried to check what may be the problem behind it.
And when I changed the datatype of one the variables from 2-D array to 2-D vector, the problem got resolved.
I am not able to understand the reason behind it. Please help me to tackle it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int optimal_weight(int W, const vector<int> &w) 
{
  int arr[w.size()+1][W+1];
  for(int i=0;i<=w.size();i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=W;j++)
    {
        if(i==0||j==0)
        arr[i][j]=0;
    }
  for(int i=0;i<=w.size();i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=W;j++)
    {
        if(i==0||j==0)
        {
            arr[i][j]=0;
            continue;
        }
        arr[i][j]=arr[i-1][j];
        if(j>=w[i-1])
        {
            arr[i][j]=std::max(arr[i][j],arr[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+w[i-1]);
        }
    }
  return arr[w.size()][W];
}

int main() {
  int n, W;
  std::cin >> W >> n;
  vector<int> w(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> w[i];
  }
  std::cout << optimal_weight(W, w) << '\n';
}
```

This is the code that throws "Unknown Signal 11" error
However, if I only change the 1st line of the optimal_weight() function from

```
int arr[w.size()+1][W+1];
```

To

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(w.size()+ 1,vector<int>(W + 1));
```

Then the problem gets resolved !

Comment: `int arr[w.size()+1][W+1];` is not legal in standard c++.There are limitations for this non-standard extension described here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: As a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, it is some unknown software (at coursera's) that emits this error for your code. That's basically not a programming question that can be answered here, because you can't provide the code for the software that shows the issues, let alone reduce it to the required [mcve] first.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks a tonne for the resource.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for the suggestion. I'll surely look into that from the next time.

Comment: `int arr[w.size()+1][W+1]` is almost certainly being allocated in Automatic storage (probably a stack) and Automatic storage is usually a very limited resource. Typically a desktop PC will offer between 1 and 10 megabytes of the stuff if you haven't made special arrangements. Let's assume the worst case of 1 MB and a 32 bit `int` and the resulting maximum of 262144 `int`s in the 2D array. Specifying dimensions as small as 500 (500 * 500 * 4 = 1,000,000)  could create an array that is too large for Automatic storage and the first you'll know of it is unpredictable program behaviour.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks a lot. I got your point.